# How to use old SSH key from Windows to Ubuntu?

Tags: git, ubuntu, ssh, smartgit

This is maybe difficult to explain, please bear with me.

I used SourceTree in Windows and used SSH to link with Github. Recently I moved to Ubuntu 14.04 LTS completely, due to HDD failure. I still have the private/public keys with me.

I installed SmartGit and now I can't seem to apply my passphrase to clone a repo from my Github account in SmartGit's SSH athentication dialog box. My question is do I have to configure the SSH in Ubuntu first? I have seen lots answer about generating new keys, but I want to use my old keys from Windows. I am completely new to Ubuntu. In SmartGit options, I opted their own SSH client. I have seen some answer about importing to .ssh folder but I am not sure if that is right choice. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally on windows you use Putty. And you have a `.ppk` file. This is a putty file format. You have to convert the file to the openssh format with **Puttygen** for example. Then you can load the key with your linux system.

Comment: SmartGit also requires SSH keys to be in *OpenSSH* format, so finally you may either use the system SSH client or SmartGit's built-in SSH client.

Comment: Can you tell me how to install puttygen? I saw this link http://linux.die.net/man/1/puttygen, but there isn't any installation notes, or is it already installed?

Comment: http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/download.html you can download it here. I think you have to convert it on windows.

Comment: This completely solved everything I need. Thank you. I can now managed to clone, commit and pushed my changes. Thank you. 

I managed to convert it on Ubuntu using:


    `puttygen mykey.ppk -O private-openssh -o my-openssh-key`